# How to prevent app uninstillation from users in group?

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play, google-play-services

i have developed one android app,have to upload in google play store and it can be accessible for specific group of people and in the group admin only has permissions to uninstall app,remaining group members will not able to uninstall.
How to prevent uninstillation from users ? and how to give permissions to admin ?
except google play store is their any stores to upload my app with my all
needs ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer - this is almost impossible.

The long answer - you can't prevent the user from uninstalling your application. Maybe on a rooted phone will work, but no on the casuals.

As addition Google Play Store or the deployment to other "Store" will not change this.

In the OEM (or just call it factory/original version) Android OS you can't stop the user from uninstalling your application.

There is an interesting platform called IBM Worklight in which there are tons of customization, orchestration and centralized management of the applications. You can check it out!

[IBM Worklight](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1208_shenoy/1208_shenoy.html)

Comment: Sorry for the immediate comment, but I'm almost 100% sure that this question is asked at least 10 times, so in order to avoid "- reputation" just try to search a bit more :)